# How to establish TLS session in python using PKCS11

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pkcs#11

I’m trying to establish TLS channel between a client and a web server that are under my control. Both the client and server authenticates themselves using certificates that I’ve created under private PKI scheme. Client key and certificate are stored on usb dongle type HSM. Python is the main application language.

I’m able to do all required crypto operations for my project using `python-pkcs11` package such as AES encryption, HMAC signing, RSA signing, and etc. However, I couldn’t find a way to “bind” pkcs11 to any TLS library. What I mean is a “Pythonic” way of calling a function that handles pkcs11 layer and establishes a TLS channel. Requests does not support pkcs11. `libcurl` has support for pkcs11 but it’s not implemented in `pycurl`, neither `pyopenssl`.

I’m able to do it openssl’s s_client CLI tool using engine api:

`openssl s_client -engine pkcs11 -verify 2 -CAfile path/to/CA.pem -keyform engine -key "pkcs11:...;object=rsa;type=private" -cert path/to/client-cert.pem -connect localhost:8443`

An example of what I’m looking for:

`do_tls_with_pkcs(key=’pkcs11:URL’, cert=’cert.pem’, verify=’CA-cert.pem’)`

As far as I could search around, no such library exists yet. Now I’m looking for a workaround.

I have read that if openssl, libp11, and python are compiled in such a way it is possible to abstract all of this, hence simple requests calls would go through HSM, transparent to application code. Although, I couldn’t find any material on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar problem as I wanted to use a PKCS#11 token (YubiKey, PIV applet) along Python [requests](http://python-requests.org).

I came up with https://github.com/cedric-dufour/scriptisms/blob/master/misc/m2requests.py

It's imperfect, in the sense that it does not use connections pools and does not support HTTP streams or proxying - like *requests*'s stock HTTPS adapter does - but it does the job for simple connections to backends that require mTLS.

Comment: I followed a different path so I can't confirm this solution but thanks anyway.

Comment: @B.Ceylan, may I ask you which path you followed? I am looking for a similar solution.